# Silverlight ChildWindow Size binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to bind ChildWindow `Height` property to my viewmodel property , but I think it only reads VM value on first load and doesn't change size when VM changes & notifies about the change. In debugger I see that it goes into Height getter once, further notifications don't change ChildWindow size..

I think it should be bindable so I am wondering whether some issue exists here or I am doing some mistake?

Sounds like one time binding, but its oneway..

```
Height="{Binding WindowHeight,Mode=OneWay}"
```

Further investigation shows that when we change binding to `Mode=TwoWay` and add an empty setter it begins to behave as expected. But that doesn't explain the reason why OneWay binding doesn't work. Also value that is passed to setter is equal to my whole application height, not just childwindow that is obviously supposed to be smaller.

The most strange thing with this whole situation is the following:

> Also this value is passed to setter
>   **4** consecutive times everytime after a getter is called (see
>   `count++` that is used to count that).

It is fired before dialog is actually shown, and it always goes in sequence `get,set,set,set,set`

Code for view model is super simple. Nowhere in code anyone is using ChildWindow Height, its only set in its xaml binding as shown above.

```
    private int count = 0;
    public int WindowHeight
    {
        get { return IsDefaultMode? DEFAULT_HEIGHT : SPECIAL_HEIGHT; }
        set {count++; }
    }
```

My inheriting Childwindow class contains like 5 strings of text none of which affect Height in any way.

Notification about WindowHeight is not fired by WindowHeight property (as seen in code) , its fired by Mode property. Couldve been a converter around mode but its currently implemented this way cause I am not sure a special converter with a couple of magic values for this situation is a better approach.

oks . mode setter code:

```
public bool IsSpecialMode
        {
            get { return m_IsSpecialMode; }
            set
            {
                if (m_IsSpecialMode!= value) 
                {
                    m_IsSpecialMode= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSpecialMode");
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("WindowHeight");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should check your "Output" window in Visual Studio for more information if the binding is breaking

Comment: @HiTech Magic: +1 for stumping me at the moment. Deleted my answer as not helpful enough. Will repost if I find something more useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ChildWindow, or any other object, changes the Height property then your binding will be lost. Try setting it to a `TwoWay` binding and set a break point in your View-model's WindowHeight property's setter. That will tell you what is setting it and whether you can have a `OneWay` binding.

The ChildWindow class will actually set it's own Height and Width properties. For example, the following code ensures the ChildWindow always covers the root content of your application. This allows the ChildWindow to provide the overlay or faded effect when showing it's popup:

```
private void UpdateOverlaySize()
{
    if (((this.Overlay != null) && (Application.Current != null)) && ((Application.Current.Host != null) && (Application.Current.Host.Content != null)))
    {
        base.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        base.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        // ... other code removed
    }
}
```

So if effect, it looks like you can't use a OneWay binding on the Height or Width properties.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However something very strange is going on! When I change it in TwoWay it begins to work fine. However I have added a counter and a count++ into my setter code and once it leaves getter , this setter is hit 4 times by what appears to be not mine code, but childwindows code or something. This probably saves binding from being changed with simple value that is read once from getter. So who is firing 4 setters and why they override oneway binding??

Comment: @Valentin - If something sets the ChildWindow.Height property, then that is the reason your binding is removed. The only way to preserve a binding when the target (i.e. ChildWindow.Height) is set is with a two-way binding. I'll update my answer with some more info.

Comment: Doh I felt something like this was behind. Thanks. Now I am wondering whether this two way binding trick i use preserves the default ChildWindow Behavior? Maybe it wont behave as it usually does, ie my setter will stop fade effects or something from working compared to default childwindow?

Comment: @Valentin - Even if your setter is empty, that doesn't mean the Height property is not going to change. It just means your view-model will be out of sync, but still bound (so changes to your view-model will be pushed to the ChildWindow). But I would probably avoid trying to set the Height/Width of the ChildWindow, and instead set the Height/Width of the content of the ChildWindow.

Comment: Ill mark this as answer however I still wonder what functionality do I lose when I dont let those 4 setter calls perform as they want..